# Discord Python Bot- fixing clear command

Tags: python, list, discord, bots, embed

my Bot has a command to clear a few words or everything...

heres my Code:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['c'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int = None):
    if amount == 0:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=10000000000000000000000)
        await ctx.send("Cleared the entire chat!")
        print("Cleared the chat!")
    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        await ctx.send("Done!")
        print(f"Cleared {amount} messages!")
```

but if i just write >clear it cleares everything... how can i say, that it clears nothning or say "enter a amount" at >clear?
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

ok fixed it...

```
@bot.command(aliases=['c'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int = None):
    if amount == 0:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=10000000000000000000000)
        await ctx.send("Cleared the entire chat!")
        print("Cleared the chat!")
    else:
        if amount >= 1:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
            await ctx.send("Done!")
            print(f"Cleared {amount} messages!")

        else:
            return
```